# Collisions between objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem looks like this:
I have one stationary object **wall** and second object that is moving **projectile**. I want **projectile** to stop when it collides with **wall**. But ewery my attempt ended with **projectile** passing through **wall**.

Only script that affects movement of **projectile**:

```
public Transform trans;
void Update()
{
     trans.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
}
```

All compomponents of **projectile**:

[image]

All components of **wall**:

[image]

Note: I have correctly set up layers in project settings.

I have tried many combinations of rigit boddies, colliders, layers and so on, but **projectile** always passed through **wall**.

Comment: You also set your projectile to trigger.

Comment: @BugFinder That does not seem right. It seems the wanted behavior is to block the projectile with the wall, and not to have the wall behaving just as a trigger outside of the physic collisions.

Comment: @E.Zacarias exactly. Yet the OP has set it to be a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your presented setup is right. The contacting object have a Rigidbody component, and the objects you can collide have at least a collider (not a trigger).

First possible problem: your Rigidbody is set to Kinematic. Did you enable all collision modes in `Project Settings > Physics > Contact Pairs Mode`?

Second problem is the use of `transform.Translate` in the `Update`. Translate will ignore physic and just move the object when you tell it to do, and `Update` may be out of sync with the physic loop, where it would be recommended to use `FixedUpdate`. Even using FixedUpdate, Translate will not do the right job. It will force the object to move and the physic can complain or not about that (it can move the object back, glitching, or it can just ignore and let the object pass).

The right way to move a Kinematic rigidbody is through `rigidbody.MovePosition`, as stated in the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html). For non-kinematic objects, you can use `AddForce`. Some tutorials also teach to set `velocity` of Rigidbody, which is not recommended because it can have undesired effects. Do it if you know the side effects and really want them.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before. May I suggest destroying the projectile instead? You will then have to use `OnCollisionEnter()`.

First, create a script and attach it to your projectile game object. After that, give your wall a tag, like 'wall'. Then, do something like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    // Gets information about the game object the projectile collided with
    GameObject objectCollided = collision.gameObject;
    if (objectCollided.tag == "wall'){
         // Do something with either the wall/enemy
    }
    // Destroy the projectile
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Note: If the intent was not to destroy the projectile but rather sticking to the wall, I suggest you to use detect collision using Raycast. Raycast has a hitInfo parameter and stores information about a gameObject that it hit, as well as the where did the Ray hit the gameObject.

Thus you can use this to move your projectile accordingly. In my previous projects, I used the Rigidbody component of my projectile and used `.AddForce()` to shoot it out, then detect collision with `OnCollisionEnter()`.

Maybe you could do the same, but have a separate function to remove that force on entering a collision. I never tried it so I do not know if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`Transform.Translate` overrides the physics engine of unity. If you want to take advantage of the rigidbody and collider components of your gameObjects, you need to use `rigidbody.Velocity` or (as unity recommends in the docs) `rigidbody.AddForce`, and make sure you set `IsKinematic` to `False` on both rigidbodies, so that they can interact with one another physically.